# Apache - Using ScriptAliasMatch to serve the home page for different URL paths

Tags: regex, apache, url, redirect, server

I have a website that uses Apache. In that website, I can go to `mywebsite.com/2020/Summer/1` and my Angular code should process the `2020/Summer/1` part. It's not like a directory or anything, it's just a way I format data for the user.

My problem is that in Apache, if you actually go to the URL above, you get a `The requested URL was not found on this server.`. Sidenote: the `DocumentRoot` is set up correctly so `mywebsite.com` works.

**How do I set up Apache so that any URL with a date path at the end just serves the homepage?**

`ScriptAliasMatch "^/[0-9]{4}/[a-zA-Z]+/[0-9]+" "/home/bitnami/myproject/dist/mywebsite"`

I think this regex should work for what I want, however when I navigate to `mywebsite.com/2020/Summer/1` I get redirected to `https://mywebsite.com/2020/Summer/3/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/(keeps going on)`.

How do I fix this? Or is there a different way in Apache to do this?

**EDIT**: my .conf file looks like this,

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/home/bitnami/myproject/dist/mywebsite"
  ScriptAliasMatch "^/[0-9]{4}/[a-zA-Z]+/[0-9]+" "/home/bitnami/myproject/dist/mywebsite"
  
  <Directory "/home/bitnami/myproject/dist/mywebsite">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny                          
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think you just want to use rewrite rules, not script alias match. Based on the URL path, you can then populate the drop downs appropriately. Besides your forward slashes not being escaped, the only thing else I'd change about your regex is making it more strict. I'd do something like `20\d{2}\/(Summer|Winter|Spring)\/\d{1,2}`

Comment: I checked and have a similar setup using `ScriptAlias` instead of `ScriptAliasmatch`. Based on this your setup looks Ok. Pure guess: Your `DocumentRoot` and `ScriptAliasmatch` point to the same directory, which might confuse Apache. Try using a different `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: I've figured out the issue. I was missing the `$` regex terminator but also I needed to directly point to the index.html and not just the `website` folder. Thanks for the responses everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  AliasMatch "^\/\d{4}\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\d{1,2}[\/]?$" "/home/bitnami/myproject/dist/mywebsite/index.html"
```

The reason why it was breaking and repeating index.html over and over was because I was missing the `$` terminator. Also added in some of Bren's suggestions.